# Breiman et al. Paper's about Classification and Regression Trees

Tags: references, cart

Where do I find the paper Breiman L., Friedman J. H., Olshen R. A., and Stone, C. J. (1984) Classification and Regression Trees. Wadsworth."?

Answer (score 3):

It is a book. So ask your local Librarian, or buy it [on line](https://www.crcpress.com/Classification-and-Regression-Trees/Breiman-Friedman-Stone-Olshen/p/book/9780412048418)

Comment: I should add that used copies on amazon are less.